# How to get the locale of the order's store?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, localisation, i18n

I have an order model. How can I get the locale from the store view where the order was created in?

**Edit**

On some tutorials I found something like

```php
/** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
$order->getStore()->getLocaleCode();
```

But this does not work (anymore).

Comment: Can you please attach a photo or more details regarding your question?

Comment: This was a general question. But I already have found a solution (see below). Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The locale of a store is defined in the store config with the path `'general/locale/code'`. To get the value of the correct store, one has to use the store ID of the order.

Here's an example how to achieve this in a helper:

```php
namespace Acme\MyModule\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    public function getOrderStoreLanguage(OrderInterface $order): ?string
    {
        $locale = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'general/locale/code',
            ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            $order->getStoreId()
        );

        if (!$locale) {
            return null;
        }

        return $locale;
    }
}
```

If you need that in another custom class, you have to inject the scope config into the constructor.

```php
namespace Acme\MyModule\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class CustomObserver
{
    private ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
}
```

Then you can get the locale of the store in the same way as in the example above.

I hope this helps other's, too.